# Is there a "YouTube-like" service for audio?

Tags: audio, podcasts

For uploading audio files (podcasts) and then embedding them in blogs and the like.

Comment: Wow! That is a lot of answers! This is gonna take a while to go through... thanks for all the answers so far!

Comment: I would suggest [Clyp](https://clyp.it/) as well

Answer (score 36):

[SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/explore) without a doubt.

- No headaches on file sizes
- Statistics on who viewed it
- Fast Uploads
- Track Storage
- Customizable widget for embedding

This is the YouTube for audio :D It’s *the stuff*.

Comment: limitation on number of minutes...

Comment: No soundcloud isn't the youtube of audio because it only lets you put x amount of storage and asks you to pay for more.

Comment: You also can't update an existing track with a new one unless you pay them money.  It is a bad choice.

Comment: While SoundCloud isn't exactly a match, it certainly is the closest to YouTube you'll probably find on the Internet in terms of adoption and selection. There are many smaller such sites out there, but they don't have nearly as many songs (well known or not) on them.

Comment: The 3 hours limitation forever kill it all. Uploading and destroying tracks is the only solution. We need a new service.

Answer (score 22):

People seem to use YouTube all the time for audio-only content as well...

Comment: +1 That was what I was thinking while reading the question

Comment: You can actually provide the audio and in the mean time show some pictures rotating or something like that.

Comment: Either pictures rotating (like a slideshow) or a fixed "title" screen detailing the name of the recording, date, etc.

By the way, if you're going to upload church recordings to Youtube, you may want to disable posting comments. Take a look at any religious video's comments to see what I mean.

Comment: Youtube's length limit makes this answer inappropriate for the poster.

Comment: The original question didn't mention any length, but now that it does - this answer is not a good answer anymore ^^

Comment: the length limit is next to being a non-factor now.

Comment: But embedding audio(only audio) from a youtube video to your website is against its terms and policies.

Comment: You may need to do that in some cases. For example, in my case, I want to play a sound effect when a button is clicked.So the video must not be visible, only the audio must be heard.

Answer (score 9):

Depends if you're talking about user created audio or licensed music.  As for licensed music there are a huge number of options (some of these also have user created content mixed in):

- [Pandora](http://pandora.com/)
- [Tunes Bag](http://en.tunesbag.com/)
- [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/en/)   (but only if you reside in the UK)
- [IMEEM](http://www.imeem.com/)
- [Playlist](http://www.playlist.com/)
- [The Hype Machine](http://hypem.com/)

On the other hand if you are looking user created content:

- [Houndbite](http://www.houndbite.com/)
- [Audio Share](http://audio-share.com/) community is small but everyone's a musician

Comment: (Nitpick: Spotify is currently available in a couple of European countries: Sweden, Norway, Finland, United Kingdom, France and Spain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify#Cost_and_availability)

Comment: also pandora don't work everywhere either (us only ?)

Comment: The Hype Machine has good music suggestions

Answer (score 7):

The one I have been finding best so far is [Grooveshark.com](http://www.Grooveshark.com) !

Answer (score 7):

I recently discovered that [archive.org](http://www.archive.org/details/audio) has a huge library of audio files, podcasts, etc. AFAIK it's pretty simple to upload, too.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about uploading music, but what about Groveshark for music streaming?

Comment: Yes, you can upload music with Grooveshark.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to post messages from your church, check out [SermonAudio.com](http://sermonaudio.com).

Comment: Looks pretty expensive to me. "Like youtube" suggests free, or somewhat close to free.

Answer (score 4):

While it's tailored for muscians, [Sound Cloud](http://soundcloud.com/) is a really good tool for sharing audio on the web.

Answer (score 2):

[soundcloud.com](http://soundcloud.com/)

> If you sign up for a free account you
>   can send 5 tracks/month and use most
>   features on SoundCloud.

Answer (score 2):

http://jukefly.com/

Manage your youtube audio :-)

Comment: excelent!!!!!!!

Comment: This service seems to have died.

Answer (score 2):

Negative on the uploading, but Pandora lets you keep playlists and is pretty good at recommending new music based on what you "like."

Answer (score 2):

[Lala](http://www.lala.com/) plays music, enables you to match your own music library (and upload the actual files if there's no match), and creates and maintains playlists. It's an iTunes-like interface, which is even more appropriate now that Apple control them (as of December 2009).

You didn't specify whether you wanted a strictly free site. Lala offers a lot for free, including uploading your own library, but adding new songs is 10 cents each and buying downloadable MP3s is around 79 cents each. Their download prices are competitive with Amazon MP3 and iTunes and are DRM-free, but be sure to check the encoding quality if that matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found a very [similar question over at webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/the-youtube-of-sound/17913#17913).  I quickly gathered most of the relevant and non-broken answers here and answered that question.  Here is that answer.

**Here are my favorite answers:**

- [Youtube](http://youtube.com) - Works just fine for audio.  You can have a static image as a background or get creative and make a slideshow or something.  Drawback: length limit
- [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/dashboard) - This would be my favorite if not for a limit on minutes of audio per account (120 minutes I think)  Its got a really nice and easy embedded player too
- [Archive.org](http://archive.org) - If you don't already know about this site, go now.

***Others I haven't had the chance to scope out yet:***

- http://tindeck.com/
- http://www.hark.com/
- http://www.freesound.org/index.php
- http://www.prx.org/help/posting-audio
- http://fizy.com/en
- http://grooveshark.com/
- http://www.tunesbag.com/
- http://hypem.com/
- http://www.houndbite.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would also add [last.fm](http://last.fm/) even though it is more like a personalised Internet Radio and doesn't work in every country anymore, but I still really like using it for discovering new Music and Events.

The problem is always the copyright thing (e.g. YouTube had trouble with the German Copyright Agency and now they must remove Music Videos under their license for German YouTube visitors... don't know if they actually did yet). Most services are only localised (like Pandora and Spotify mentioned by William). So probably YouTube is still the best and most popular source for playing Music.

One service that doesn't have that problem is [Jamendo](http://jamendo.com). It only offers music that is published under free licences. You won't find popular artists but browsing there might bring up some really cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Tindeck](http://www.tindeck.com/) provides free MP3 audio hosting.

Answer (score 1):

[Entertonement](http://www.entertonement.com/) Is very similar to youtube but only for audio.  Plus it has [amazing collections](http://www.entertonement.com/collections) of soundbites that are fun to browse through.  [They don't mention](http://www.entertonement.com/static/learn-more#upload) any limits on upload lengths either, although they still might exist.

Answer (score 1):

PRX = [Public Radio Exchange](http://www.prx.org/help/posting-audio)

Answer (score 1):

http://freesound.org has a ton of free audio files available for playing online or downloading.  I think it's better than youtube.