# Is there any music streaming service that i can embed on my site?

Tags: music, streaming, embed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a “youtube like” service for audio ?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/933/is-there-a-youtube-like-service-for-audio)

Videos got YouTube
Photos got Flickr

Are there similar services for music?

Comment: I use [fizy](http://fizy.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://soundcloud.com/

> SoundCloud is an online audio distribution platform which allows musicians to collaborate, promote and distribute their music. It has sometimes been described as being for audio what Flickr is for photos, or Vimeo is for video.

*From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundCloud)*

Hope this helps.